# Project is missing required library - but correct JAR exists?

Tags: java, eclipse

One of my eclipse projects gives me the `Project X is missing required library: 'somelib.jar'` error, but when I go to **Configure Build Path > Libraries** the library *is* present, and no error is indicated there.

I tried the usual things:

- Clean build (all projects in the workspace)
- Exited eclipse multiple times

My coworkers, using the same git checkout with the same status as mine, and also using eclipse Neon2, have no build errors.

Just to be sure, I navigated into the corresponding directory and removed a *different* jar file, and when I look at my build path configuration *that* jar shows up with a red "x" indicating that the library is missing.

I checked that `somelib.jar` sits in the expected place and is a valid JAR file.

How do I fix this?

Comment: try to remove library - clean and add again

Comment: As an FYI to anyone else who stumbles on this : This problem/solution for Eclipse applies to VSCode too, where the Java Extensions for VSCode from RedHat uses Eclipse underpinnings. Be sure that you've actually saved your project/workspace (different concepts), then restart and update the .classpath file. Also note that "lib" entries in .classpath must be grouped together. It seems if that file has "con", "lib", "output", "lib", it won't find the second lib. You need con, lib, lib, output. HTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some times eclipse becomes naughty following steps should be taken to nicely add the jar library in project

- First remove the library from libs folder
- Also remove the refrence from java build path in external library tab
- Clean the project let it actually realize the library is missing :D
- Again copy the jar file in libs folder
- Add the refrence of library in java build path library tab
- set the priority of this library to top (important) because its
  possible the order of library export is not ok in your project
- Clean the project and build

  hope so it will solve your problem

Comment: Helpful as well. But just in case ... I already received a downvote on my question ... making me wonder if I should rather delete it. So maybe, when you have an idea what i could do to improve the question, let me know ...

Comment: I did not down voted it your question is right this problem is widely generated in the eclipse every 4th person who is using eclipse is experiencing this

Comment: Well. I am using eclipse since 10 years - and it is the first time that I saw *this* problem.

Comment: i am using Eclipse since 5 years with ADT bundle and almost for each project of android i imported i have go to go through this may be some version change . .

Answer (score 7):

These steps did resolve the problem:

- **closing** / re-opening the corresponding project
- another "full" clean of all projects in the workspace

In other words: it seems that a simple F5 "refresh" and a even a "clean project" isn't sufficient sometimes. So *closing* the project is the key element here!

Comment: sometimes eclipse goes crazy (version indipendent) once i had a similar problem and i solved in that way as i answered above . Could be an isolate case , non standard case!

Comment: Ehy man , with 62.4k i think you should have the enough experience how to make question and how to answer. You can always improve of course ..but in my opinion there is no thing wrong in your question .

Comment: @Frank We are all just humans here. Sometimes you simply overlook something ... but it doesn't seem to be the case here. So - thanks for your time and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple projects opened in such way that one depends on another, and the problematic project depends on others, refreshing all dependent projects will fix the 'missing library' issue for the main project.